# install Chinese(and other utf-8) fonts for Xvfb?

Tags: chinese, utf-8, xvfb

I have installed these packages:

```
apt-get install xvfb xfonts-base xfonts-75dpi xfonts-100dpi firefox
```

But in my `Firefox` in `Xvfb` on `Ubuntu Server`, the Chinese characters look like:

[image: screenshot]

How to install proper fonts for my Xvfb?

**EDIT**: I have also installed `xfonts-intl-chinese` but it doesn't help.

Comment: I'm also having this problem.  I'm using selenium in this https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/StandaloneChromeDebug docker image. After installing `xfonts-wqy`, Chinese charactors still do not show correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

You need `xfonts-wqy` as well. (it's a open-source Chinese font)

```
sudo apt-get install xfonts-wqy
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a Ubuntu server installation, I installed a bunch of font packages to solve my problem. It is the complete list, I do not know which one really fixed it, but xfonts-wqy did not only fix it for some use-cases on my system.

```
fonts-dejavu-core
fonts-dejavu-extra
fonts-droid-fallback
fonts-guru
fonts-guru-extra
fonts-horai-umefont
fonts-kacst
fonts-kacst-one
fonts-khmeros-core
fonts-lao
fonts-liberation
fonts-lklug-sinhala
fonts-lohit-guru
fonts-nanum
fonts-noto-cjk
fonts-opensymbol
fonts-roboto
fonts-roboto-hinted
fonts-sil-abyssinica
fonts-sil-padauk
fonts-stix
fonts-symbola
fonts-takao-pgothic
fonts-thai-tlwg
fonts-tibetan-machine
fonts-tlwg-garuda
fonts-tlwg-kinnari
fonts-tlwg-laksaman
fonts-tlwg-loma
fonts-tlwg-mono
fonts-tlwg-norasi
fonts-tlwg-purisa
fonts-tlwg-sawasdee
fonts-tlwg-typewriter
fonts-tlwg-typist
fonts-tlwg-typo
fonts-tlwg-umpush
fonts-tlwg-waree
fonts-unfonts-core
fonts-wqy-microhe
```