# How can I install Chinese fonts on Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, fonts, chinese

I'd like to see Chinese characters, such as [this](http://www.isthisthingon.org/unicode/?page=X8&subpage=B&glyph=X8BDD) one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This package seems to have a complete Chinese font:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-wqy-zenhei
```

I see that it installs it to:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/wqy/wqy-zenhei.ttc
```

Sometimes, the system DejaVuSans font is used as a fallback:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf
```

As part of an earlier attempt, I also installed a bunch of fonts with:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-arphic-bkai00mp fonts-arphic-bsmi00lp fonts-arphic-gbsn00lp fonts-arphic-gkai00mp fonts-arphic-ukai fonts-arphic-uming fonts-cns11643-kai fonts-cns11643-sung fonts-cwtex-fs fonts-cwtex-heib fonts-cwtex-kai fonts-cwtex-ming fonts-cwtex-yen
```

and I see that `fonts-arphic-ukai` added `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/arphic/ukai.ttc`, which seems to have a very complete set of Chinese characters.

Comment: I had the same issue in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/189945/install-chineseand-other-utf-8-fonts-for-xvfb,  `fonts-wqy-zenhei` totally saved me.

Comment: That particular font file came from `fonts-arphic-ukai`: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/fonts-arphic-ukai

Comment: ah, you so much help me, I spent so much time to fix absent Chinese characters

Answer (score 2):

You can download font files from [this website](http://cooltext.com/Fonts-Unicode-Chinese) for example. After that you open them (with Font Viewer or your equivalent program) and click install. Simple as that!

If you'd like to view all characters at once and browse through them I recommend you to try out GNOME Character Map, if you haven't already.

Comment: So do any of the fonts that come with Kubuntu 14.04 support the full range of Chinese characters? I can see some characters with the system fonts, but others are squares.

Comment: I installed xfonts-intl-chinese and xfonts-intl-chinese-big, but I still see some squares.

Comment: I also installed http://cooltext.com/Download-Font-%E7%B2%97%E6%A5%B7%E4%BD%93%E7%AE%80+Kai+Bold from that site, but I still see squares... I'm starting to think this may be an issue with my Qt build.